# Updating a view from collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am having a little trouble rendering my player.
Im trying to create a structure using backbonejs that will

- Add a new player view when a new player joins
- Updates a player score

In `updatePlayerData` I update the player score if the player model has already been created. If not I create a new one.

The problem is in `playerScore`. I am creating a span everytime `render` is called. This is causing many `player` `classes` to be creating under the one player view

I need to be able to loop through my current views and update the player of a certain id. I need to then re render that player view so the new content is displayed.

For reference here is my code so far:

```
var Player = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var PlayerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: 'player',
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');

    },
    render: function () {
        this.playerScore();
        return this;
    },
    playerScore: function(){
        $('<span/>', {
            class: 'playerScore'
        }).appendTo($(this.el)).html(this.model.get('score'));

    }
});

var Team = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Player
});

var TeamView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#users',
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'updatePlayerData', 'addPlayer');
        this.collection.bind('add', this.addPlayer);
        this._subviews = [];
    },
    updatePlayerData: function (playerEntity) {
        var view = _(this._subviews).find(function(v){
                return playerEntity.id == v.model.get('id');
        });
        if(view){
            view.model.set({
                score: playerEntity.score
            });
            view.render();
            return;
        }
        var playerModel = new Player();
        playerModel.set({
            score: playerEntity.score
        });
        this.collection.add(playerModel);
    },
    addPlayer: function (player) {
        var playerView = new PlayerView({
            model: player
        });
        var playerHtml = playerView.render().el;
        $(this.el).html(playerHtml);
        this._subviews.push(playerView);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your `playerScore` method to something like:

```
playerScore: function () {
    if (!$(this.el).find('span.playerScore').length) {
        $('<span/>', {
            class: 'playerScore'
        }).appendTo($(this.el)).html(this.model.get('score'));
    } else {
        $(this.el).find('span.playerScore').html(this.model.get('score'));
    }
}
```